# Push variable from loop into array that is indexed

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked around for awhile and haven't found any solutions. What I'm trying to do is store the variable that contains my option values into an array with an index for each element that is in the variable so I can call it's index.

Here is my code:

```js
var selectArray = ['Package 1', 'Package 2'];
var selectField = document.getElementById('testS');


 for(i = 0; i < selectArray.length; i++) {
  let arrayList = selectArray[i];
  let arrayOption = document.createElement('option');
  selectField.appendChild(arrayOption);
  arrayOption.value = arrayList; // Value Option in Option
  arrayOption.innerHTML = arrayList; // Text in Option


  let newArray = [];

  newArray.push(arrayOption.value);
    // This doesn't work I want each element in the variable to be indexed in the array. so I can do for example newArray[0] which will return Package 1 from the value.



 }
```

```html
<select name="fromList" id="testS"></select>
```

Reason I'm trying to push the option values from my loop variable into the array is because I want to select each of there index and append to them another array that contains data.

Comment: First, you need to declare newArray outside of the for loop. But, even after doing that won't newArray be the exact same as selectArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change where you are declaring the `newArray`. `let` creates block level scope, so if you delcare it within a loop, it is scoped to just that one iteration of the loop. You don't want the variable re-declared upon each iteration of the loop because that wipes out the earlier value.

```js
var selectArray = ['Package 1', 'Package 2'];
var selectField = document.getElementById('testS');

// You need to declare variables in the scope that you will want to use them
let newArray = [];

 for(i = 0; i < selectArray.length; i++) {
  let arrayList = selectArray[i];
  let arrayOption = document.createElement('option');
  selectField.appendChild(arrayOption);
  arrayOption.value = arrayList; // Value Option in Option
  arrayOption.innerHTML = arrayList; // Text in Option

  newArray.push(arrayOption.value);
 }
  
console.log(newArray);
```

```html
<select name="fromList" id="testS"></select>
```

Now, the next question is why do you really need to even do this? The `option` elements in the `select` can always be gotten on-demand as an array with this:

```
var options = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#testS > option"));
```

Comment: Oh I see. The problem was with scope. I guess I need a refresher course on scope. I'll make sure to go back and touch on this concept. Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Curious13 You're welcome. See my last update at the bottom for a bit more and don't forget to mark this as "the" answer.

Comment: I see. I didn't know you could do that. I guess I was trying my own approach haha. But anyway, I was trying to select there index in the array so I can append to them other values